# Password-change email could be more helpful

Tags: feature-request, email, password

Having changed my Stack Exchange password today, I noticed that the confirmation email includes the text:

> If you didn't do this, you should be worried.

Whilst this is perfectly true and valid, if I *didn't* change my password, I *would* be worried and I would be frantically trying to work out what to do. In such circumstances it would really help to have a link to some advice!